# vc_varsall.bat and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-2015

The function **find_vcvarsall** in **distutils.msvc9compiler** checks several locations (env variables or registry) to find **vc_varsall.bat**. I've called the function on several different machines with VS 2015 installed and none of them returned the path. Sometimes the environment variable for VS130COMNTOOLS is not set and/or the registry *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio*) entry is missing. On all machines it works for 2012, 2013, and 2017. Any ideas?

**TL;DR:** Why is every Visual Studio listed in the registry, except for VS2015?

[image: Missing 13.0 for Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 lives in the 14.0 directory.

Comment: How could I miss that? This version numbering by MS drives me crazy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**get_build_version()** in Python 2.7 returns the wrong build version if Python was compiled with MSC v. 1900 (Visual Studio 2015). I used **msvc9compiler.get_build_version** from Python 3.6, which explicitly fixes this issue